# What obvious thing am I overlooking in this failing C++ class instantiation?

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I'm writing code for an Arduino-based retirement countdown clock (a gift for a coworker), and have grouped some code into a simple class.  This chunk of code gives me the error "error: 'rd' does not name a type" when I compile it in the current (1.6.7) Arduino IDE:

```
#include "RetirementDisplay.h"
RetirementDisplay* rd;
rd = new RetirementDisplay(&update_lcd);
```

Oddly, this code compiles without error:

```
#include "RetirementDisplay.h"
RetirementDisplay* rd = new RetirementDisplay(&update_lcd);
```

But then when I try to use a member function (like `rd->add_screen()`) of the newly created rd object, I get the same "rd does not define a type" error, which is completely illogical to me.  My C++ is super rusty, though, so I assume there's probably something I'm overlooking here.

The update_lcd method is defined earlier in the same file, and does take two String arguments, so I don't think it's upset about that.

The contents of RetirementDisplay.h are similarly simple; it's just a linked list and a couple of convenience functions to bundle related functionality together while tracking what "screen" (just a couple of printf formats) should currently be active.  Don't judge me on my sketchy naming convention; this was supposed to be a quick project. ;)

```
#ifndef RetirementDisplay_h
#define RetirementDisplay_h

#include "RetirementScreen.h"
class RetirementDisplay {
protected:
  RetirementScreen* head;
  RetirementScreen* current;
  void (*updater)(String, String);
public:
  RetirementDisplay( void(*)(String,String) );
  void add_screen(RetirementScreen*);
  void update();
  void next();
  void prev();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Any particular reason `add_screen` has one underscore in the header and two when you tried to use it? And can you give a complete file where you try to use it and it breaks?

Comment: You can't have statements at file scope. Only declarations may appear there; statements must be within a function. `rd = new RetirementDisplay(&update_lcd);` is a statement. `RetirementDisplay* rd = new RetirementDisplay(&update_lcd);` is a declaration with an initializer.

Comment: Two underscores because I worked 13 hours today and my typing fingers are a bit sketchy. :)  Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this line is intended to be an assignment statement:

```
rd = new RetirementDisplay(&update_lcd);
```

but statements must be inside functions, like this:

```
#include "RetirementDisplay.h"

void myfunction()
{
    RetirementDisplay* rd;
    rd = new RetirementDisplay(&update_lcd);
}
```

However, variable declarations can be outside functions, so that is why you don't get an error on this line:

```
RetirementDisplay* rd = new RetirementDisplay(&update_lcd);
```

Comment: Ok, that'd do it. I was falling into the trap of don't initialization stuff outside of the setup()  method where that really should go in the Arduino environment. Thamks. :)